# C# - How to inject new instance of dependency to a class which get instantiated once in the app lifetime?

Tags: c#, design-patterns, dependency-injection, anti-patterns

Here is a class which will be instantiated only once through out the lifetime of the application

```
public class SampleClass //instantiated only once
 {
  public void DoOpertation()//will be called by every incoming request
   {
     var dependentService = new SampleService();
     //do operation on dependentService instance
     ....
   }
  }
```

Method "DoOpertation" operation will be called many time during the application lifetime.

In "DoOpertation" method I'm instantiating 'SampleService' using 'new' keyword which I don't want to do for the below reasons

1. It breaks single responsibility principle (SRP) as creating SampleService class instance is not SampleClass's responsibility
2. Create tight coupling between SampleClass & SampleService classes which makes unit testing harder atleast

***I can't use DI container for constructor injection of dependencies as SampleClass get instantiated only once in the application lifetime*** but where as every invocation of DoOpertation method (which lives inside SampleClass) requires new instance of SampleService class to work properly.

How to inject SampleService class new instance on every invocation of DoOpertation() without using 'new' keyword?

**Modification as per Athanasios Kataras's suggestion**

Introduced new factory class

```
        public class LoggerFactory : ILoggerFactory
        {
            public IEventLog CreateLogger(string type)
            {
                if (type == "Event")
                    return new EventLog();
                else
                    return null;
            }
        }

        public interface ILoggerFactory
        {
            IEventLog CreateLogger(string type);
        }
```

On the class which instantiate only once,

```
 public class SampleClass //instantiated only once
   {
    public void DoOpertation()//will be called by every incoming request
    {
      var eventLogBuilder = _factory.CreateLogger("Event");
     //var dependentService = new SampleService(); //replace with above simple factory class call
     //do operation on dependentService instance
     ....
   }
  }
```

Comment: Is the java tag relevant here?

Answer (score 0):

I would go with a simple factory solution.

1. Create the `IServiceFactory` interface with the `CreateService(options)` function
2. Create a class implementing it with the responsibility of returning the proper service insurance.
3. Inject the factory implementation

In your function call the factory interface. This will also enable you to change the creation strategy in the future if you need it.

The solution going with the built in provider, looks like a service locator anti pattern to me, so I would advise against it.

Comment: any other solutions? because creating factory is bit out of context & there is no scope to change the creation strategy in the future. Me too agree of not going with service locator anti pattern.

Comment: You can always pass the service as a function parameter but that just delegates the issue one level up. It makes sense in some cases though but it resembles functional programming more. If the caller isn't singleton it makes much more sense.

Comment: By the way, object creation should be very cheap. That being the case, if you have no state you want to maintain inside the class, creating it every time would be the best way to go.

Comment: yeah tried out passing of service as function parameter as other option before doing this post but not convinced as that delegates the issue just one level up. Otherwise if Im going with factory option, factory method has to use either IServiceProvider or new operator to render the brand new instance of 'SampleService' class, is that okay? or there is different way of doing it?

Comment: I'd go with the new operator, no use coupling with the service provider

Comment: how about [this] (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio#:~:text=private%20async%20Task,scopedProcessingService.DoWork(stoppingToken)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D) where microsoft used ServiceProvider to create service instance, it isn't anti-pattern?

Comment: This is boiler plate background task. It's like coupling the service provider with the startup code. Kind of like dependency injection but for background tasks.

Comment: @ Athanasios Kataras,  Modified code with the factory code suggestion. But really not convinced what additional value it brings instead of directly using the 'new' operator. May be I can unit test SampleClass but not the LoggerFactory. Is that what you mean? or  have I missed something else?

Answer (score 0):

Register Sampleclass as a singleton and SampleService as a transient.
Then inject IServiceProvider into SampleClass. Use the ServiceProvider to then create the SampleServer.

```
services.AddSingleton<SampleClass>();
services.AddTransient<SampleService>();

...

public class SampleClass //instantiated only once
{
    private readonly IServiceProvider _provider;
    
    public SampleClass(IServiceProvider provider)
    {
        _provider = provider;
    }
    
    public void DoOpertation()//will be called by every incoming request
    {
    var dependentService = _provider.GetService<SampleService>();
    //do operation on dependentService instance
    ....
    }
}
```

Comment: While this works, it looks a lot like service locator anti pattern.